# How to write date and number in Chinese?

Tags: translation, mandarin

I need to fill a part of a form in Chinese, does anyone here could help me?

I've tried to use google translate, but unfortunately, I know nothing about Chinese and I'm afraid I was wrong, please help me.

How to write the following  in Chinese?

```
1. "Z53120385"     is this true (Z五三一二零三八)?

2. " 11/03/2010"   is this true (十一 / 三 /二十二)?
```

Comment: You can just write the digits and letter. No "translation" needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "Z53120385"     is

   Z五三一二零三八五

And there is a formal version in capital Chinese character:

Z伍叁壹贰零叁捌伍 (usually used as price in contract)

2. " 11/03/2010"   is

   2010年03月11日

Chinese dates use numbers as a custom, there is no need to force translating. Or you can also use

```
2010/03/11 as Year/Month/day.
```

If you do need a full Chinese dates in a formal document, it should be

```
"二零一零年三月十一日".
```

I don't know what the number means, but in general, I presume there is no need to translate other than using dates in Year/Month/day. Because Chinese used to use letters and Arabic numbers in many situations like serial number, ticket number, dates and so on.

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, in daily life, modern Chinese people use just the Arabic digits. So as a native speaker of Chinese, I feel weird when see you guys use so many Chinese numbers.

In daily life, we use Chinese character to represent number in the receipt or bank things to confirm the digits are not changed, and we have a set of "大写数字" for money thing：

- 壹 1
- 贰 2
- 叁 3
- 肆 4
- 伍 5
- 陆 6
- 柒 7
- 捌 8
- 玖 9
- 零 0
- 拾 10
- 佰 100
- 仟 1000
- 万 1 0000
- 亿 1 0000 0000

(Notice that in Chinese we add space every 4 digits)

For time, it is also the case: in daily life, use Arabic digits. Just remember unlike in English, in Chinese, we say things from big to small.  This "zoom in" rule is good for all range-ish concepts.(Time, date, address).

```
  中国         河北省             石家庄市
 China  Hebei Province     Shijiazhuang City

   2020年       4月     2日
  year 2020     April    2nd

  上午           9点
   AM         9 o'clock
```

Also, in daily life, Chinese Character date are sometimes used.  We use "元月" for January sometimes ("一月" is of course right and more common), and "〇" for zero.
Sample can be found [here](http://www.xinhuanet.com/politics/2019-12/31/c_1125410025.htm).

Answer (score 0):

First: numbers like 11, 20 and 10 would not be eleven, twenty and ten - they are combinations of single digits 1 + 1, 2 + 0, and 1 + 0.

Second: Chinese dates go YYYY.MM.DD.

The minders Chinese date would be written: 2010.11.03 if you insist on using Chinese characters you can, it’d be something like this: 二零一零。一一。零三

Comment: Thanks! is my first one was true? I mean "Z53120385" was true?

Comment: I’m not sure how to read Z53120385.

Answer (score 0):

For everyday usage:

> 1. "Z53120385"     is this true (Z五三一二零三八)?

No, we don't use Chinese characters in codes. Just fill in "Z53120385".

> 2. " 11/03/2010"   is this true (十一 / 三 /二十二)?

This is a date. The most common way we write is "2010年11月3日". We also use "10年11月3日"、“2010-11-03”、“2010/11/03”. Unlike Americans, we prefer "yy/mm/dd" or "dd/mm/yy" to "mm/dd/yy".

If you want to use Chinese characters only, you can write "二〇一〇年十一月三日". Note that "〇" is an existing Chinese character, and it is only used in numbers. In long numbers and years, "〇" is preferred over "零". But in accounting, the capitalized accounting number can be only presented as "零" to prevent tampering.